# GPU accelerated collision

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, collision-detection, gpu

Has anyone tried accelerating collision detection via GPU? I thought about passing position+radius for a simple sphere intersection, rendering all intersecting triangle indices to a texture.

**Using the GPU**

I'm not sure if this is an good idea at all, but the math doesn't seem to be costly for this in vertex shader. It wouldn't resolve anything, just fetching the face indices to indicate which faces are relevant. It's also only supposed for the terrain.

**Using the octree**

The terrain is generated via dual contouring, and in it's highest lod several thousand nodes can be required, storing face indices based on the dual cells or connecting them to their octree nodes are costly in terms of memory and cpu. It already required a lot optimizations and needs to run multi-threaded, i'd like to avoid additional steps on this side.

It might work using the octree and the density function on the boundaries and trilinear interpolating the surface, but it requires to pass the nodes from the worker, or position to worker. Anyway this wouldn't completely match the polygons of a cell, but at least smooth out the error.

**Using the density function**

While required octree-nodes and their polygons are adaptive, their size are varying much, so a collision based on the density field function won't always fit the actual underlying geometry, surface can be far below or above the geometry.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I know there are various lighting methods which are very similiar to what you are trying to do here. Stuff like http://simonstechblog.blogspot.ca/2013/01/implementing-voxel-cone-tracing.html. However, I do not think GPU accelerated collision is necessary. If you build your collision detection correctly, that is with a broad phase with correct spatial partitioning and then a narrow phase, JS  should be more than sufficient.